# Spring boot client server authentication and authorization with jwt

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

The application requires to be authenticated and authorized from SSO.
All the required information is present in the JWT, but I'm not sure if this the correct approach as `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken` is null.

The client server `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is as follows

```java
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();

        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(
                new OfficeUserAuthProvider()
            );
    }
}
```

and `OfficeUserAuthProvider` is as follows

```java
public class OfficeUserAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OfficeUserAuthProvider.class);

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken auth = (OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        logger.info("{}", authentication);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        logger.info("{}", OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
        return OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }


}
```

The output from `logger.info("{}", authentication);` is

```
22-01-31 Mon 01:25:15.700 INFO  c.t.s.config.OfficeUserAuthProvider      Java : 27    : OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken [Principal=null, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=FF16A2C206F66F021109D86C4997F8F6], Granted Authorities=[]]
```

The decoded JWT token received from authorization serve is

```
{
  "dateTime": 1643570398335,
  "aud": [
    "documentRepository"
  ],
  "user_name": "admin",
  "enable": true,
  "scope": [
    "read",
    "write"
  ],
  "exp": 1643572198,
  "department": null,
  "authorities": [
    "ROLE_ADMIN_USER",
    "ROLE_OFFICE_USER"
  ],
  "jti": "bbc551c4-31ec-4744-bc92-c051f5c08719",
  "client_id": "appXXXX"
}
```

and `application.property` of client server is

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xyz.client-id=appXXXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xyz.client-secret=passXXXXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xyz.client-name=app
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xyz.scope=read, write
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xyz.provider=xyz-sso
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xyz.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8081/login/oauth2/code/
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xyz.client-authentication-method=post
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xyz.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xyz-sso.authorization-uri=http://modern-14-b4mw:8080/oauth/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xyz-sso.token-uri=http://modern-14-b4mw:8080/oauth/token
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by having the `OfficeUserAuthProvider`?

Comment: Its for the logging in the `Authentication` object. After successful login i cant get the Authentication object from the  oauth2Login. The client application is based on `authorities` (roles) present in the JWT json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to improvise and implemented a rest end point for the `Principal`
`/user/me` in the SSO

in client `application.property` added

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xyz-sso.user-info-uri=http://modern-14-b4mw:8080/api//user/me
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xyz-sso.user-name-attribute=name
```

with the above update was able to get `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`